# How to rigorously show that if $x$ is of Order $m$ then $x^k$ is of order $\frac{\text{lcm}(m,k)}{k}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to show the seemingly obvious fact that if $x$ is of Order $m$ then $x^k$ is of order $\frac{\text{lcm}(m,k)}{k}$. I'm struggling with rigorously showing this fact, as I don't know of a closed way to write the lcm. Also, the group to be considered is not necessarily abelian or finite.

Is there a more elegant, indirect way to show this fact without a way to write the lcm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write $o(x)$ for the order of $x$, I most frequently see this claim as

$$o(x^k) = \frac{o(x)}{\text{gcd}(o(x),k)}$$

This (equivalent) statement might give a better idea of how to prove the claim.

---

Let $d = \text{gcd}(o(x),k)$. 
Then $o(x) = dn$ and $k = dm$ with $n$ and $m$ coprime.

We want to show $o(x^k) = n$

First, we see $o(x^k)$ divides $n$:

$$(x^k)^n = (x^{dm})^n = (x^{dn})^m = (x^{o(x)})^m = e^m = e$$

Can you use [Bezout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) to show that $o(x^k)$ actually *equals* $n$?
A full solution can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_Power_of_Group_Element) if you get stuck.

---

I hope this helps ^_^